# Using Method and passing values to main method

Tags: c#

So I have a question that ask for a Movies method, to accept a name as string and a integer(represents time in minutes). So if you call this method without an integer minutes is set to a default of 90. Then the main method shows that you can call the movies method with only a string as well show you can call it with a string and integer.

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Movie title is {0}, and time is", MovieListing("x") );
}

private static string MovieListing(string name, int defaultTime = 60)
{
    string Name, stringTime;
    int time;
    bool isValid;
    Console.Write("What is the name of the movie?");
    Name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("What is the time of the movie? Default is 90 if left blank");
    stringTime = Console.ReadLine();
    time = Convert.ToInt32(stringTime);           
}
```

So Im left blank thinking how to get the program to tell if the user entered a time int and use that or if they are just using the default 90 and passing them back to the main method sorry if the codes a mess was trying different ways without much success

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin: He has those already.

Comment: Your question is unclear. How to tell if the user entered a time is to check to see that stringTime is not empty. That is obvious, and I don't know why you would need to ask that as a question, so what are you really trying to figure out?

Comment: How are you supposed to return the two values since a function can have only 1 return argumet ? I doubt that you have to use ref/out. Please update the question with the exact requirement ot the task.

Comment: By the way, if you are just starting out in C#, consider popping over to [CodeReview StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for reviews of your code. It can be a big help while you're learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ternary operation to check if the entered value is empty:

```
time = string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringTime) ? defaultTime  : Convert.ToInt32(stringTime);
```

It will parse the `stringTime` if filled, else it will take the default.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best way to solve the problem as stated.

Comment: Totally forgot about using the IsNullOrEmpty!  Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better way to do this, using a simple `Movie` object to hold the values. This should print out two hardcoded lines to demo and then ask the user for input:

```
private class Movie 
{
    private readonly int _defaultLength = 90;

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }

    // constructor without length - use default length
    public Movie(string title)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Length = _defaultLength;
    }

    // constructor with both properties
    public Movie(string title, int length)
    {
        this.Title = title;

        // make sure Length is valid
        if (length > 0)
            this.Length =length;
        else
            this.Length = _defaultLength;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    // make a Movie object without length
    var shortMovie = new Movie("Zombieland");

    // make a Movie object and specify length
    var longMovie = new Movie("Lawrence of Arabia", 216);

    Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1} minutes long", shortMovie.Title, shortMovie.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1} minutes long", longMovie.Title, longMovie.Length);

    // get input from user: title
    Console.Write("What is the name of another movie?");
    var userTitle = Console.ReadLine();

    // get input from user: length
    Console.Write("What is the length of {0}? Default is 90 if left blank", userTitle);
    var userTime = Console.ReadLine();

    // try to convert user input to an int and call Movie constructor to create a new object
    int userTimeConverted = 0;
    Movie userMovie;
    if (Int32.TryParse(userTime, out userTimeConverted))
    {
        // make a new Movie object with the user's input
        userMovie = new Movie(userTitle, userTimeConverted);
    }
    else
    {
        // make a new Movie object without the user's input
        userMovie = new Movie(userTitle);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1} minutes long", longMovie.Title, longMovie.Length);
}
```

By building a separate `Movie` object, we can move most or all of the logic needed for storing a default length and checking to see if the length is valid out of the `Main()` method. This should hopefully be much cleaner and easier to read.

As an added bonus, we can create as many instances of `Movie` as we want - as demonstrated in the above code.

Comment: Yes, but doing a try parse, without actually handling properly is bad coding in my opinion. +1 anyways. You did a lot of work for this post.

Comment: You mean calling it without branching on or storing the `bool` result? And thanks. Cheers!

Comment: If you try to parse something there should always be a good/bad decision. In this case the use of a different constructor makes totally sense.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default value to something you wouldnt expect the user to enter and detect and handle that.

```
private static string MovieListing(string name, int defaultTime = -1)
{
    var isDefaultUsed = false;
    if (defaultTime = -1)
    {
       isDefaultUsed = true;
       defaultTime = 60;
    }
    string Name, stringTime;
    int time;
    bool isValid;
    Console.Write("What is the name of the movie?");
    Name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("What is the time of the movie? Default is 90 if left blank");
    stringTime = Console.ReadLine();
    time = Convert.ToInt32(stringTime);           
}
```